# Writing my first shiny app, How do I plot by selected variables, why does this script not work?

Tags: r, shiny, r-highcharter

I'm trying to write my first shiny app that will give some statistical analysis between two variables and a plot that shows a relationship between them. My data will be predetermined. For the graph, I've decided to use highcharter but how do I write the code for this? The above code is my first try but I can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work. I've tried the example code for shiny from the highcharter guide too but it doesn't seem to work either.

```
library(shiny)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput("First", label = "First Variable", width = "100%",
              choices = colnames(iris)), 
  selectInput("Second", label = "Second", width = "100%",
              colnames(iris)),
  highchartOutput("hchartcont")

)

server = function(input, output) {

  output$hchartcont <- renderHighchart({
    hc <- highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type="line") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(input$First) %>% 
      hc_yAxis_multiples(input$Second)
    hc
  }

  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `highcharter` so nothing stands out, but: *"it doesn't work"* would do much better if you explained why and how it isn't working (including verbatim errors/warnings from the console and small screenshot of the web page with problems, if visual) and what is expected.

Comment: curious ... where in your highchart code do you tell it what data to use? From the [shiny events demo](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/shiny-events-demo.html) vignette, it has `highchart() %>% hc_add_series(df, "scatter") %>% ...` which is where it appears to identify the dataset to use. I don't see `iris` referenced in a way where `highchart` would know to use it.

Comment: Isn't your chart a reactive one? I mean, it depends on some inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not familiar with `highcharter`, your code doesn't seem to provide any data to the plot. You need to get the input data first and then draw a plot.

For example, this could work (I tried to preserve as much of your code as possible... the line plot does not make sense here, however; consider this to be only a quick working example :-)):

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput("First", label = "First Variable", width = "100%",
                choices = colnames(iris)), 
    selectInput("Second", label = "Second", width = "100%",
                choices = colnames(iris)),
    highchartOutput("hchartcont")

)

server = function(input, output) {

    output$hchartcont <- renderHighchart({
        df <- iris %>% select(x = input$First, y = input$Second)
        hchart(df, "line", hcaes(x, y))
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. Seems like what I actually needed was to understand how to place the data into the graph. You saved me a lot.